# T-SQL substring between delimiters in middle of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to pull a substring from a string where there are multiple same delimiters. Has to be done in a sql query (no function calls, etc.)

Example of data:

```
DI:TIER1:VQ:SPI:H:SID005000009MTED0:FDCADIND:PS
PA:TIER4:VQ:SPI:H:SID005000009V3VO7:STPACPB3:CI
```

The data I need is between the last and second to last colons.

Data:

```
FDCADIND
STPACPB3
```

Data will always be in the same position. Last three characters will always be format of :XX

I started on a query but can't seem to get it to reverse correctly.

```
Select SubString('DI:TIER1:VQ:SPI:H:SID005000009MTED0:FDCADIND:PS', (CHARINDEX(':', 'DI:TIER1:VQ:SPI:H:SID005000009MTED0:FDCADIND:PS', 0) + 1), 
        (CharIndex(':', RIGHT('DI:TIER1:VQ:SPI:H:SID005000009MTED0:FDCADIND:PS', (LEN('DI:TIER1:VQ:SPI:H:SID005000009MTED0:FDCADIND:PS') - (CharIndex(':', 'DI:TIER1:VQ:SPI:H:SID005000009MTED0:FDCADIND:PS', 0)))), 0) - 1)) As NewString
```

Any help appreciated,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data (last two fields) are of fixed length:

```
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT('DI:TIER1:VQ:SPI:H:SID005000009MTED0:FDCADIND:PS',11),8)
```